# Pass regex match to variable from console.log to display output in textbox

Tags: javascript, regex

What I want to achieve is to have the values stored in console.log passed to my textbox.

Let's say my list (result) looks like this:

```
Line 1 abc apple abc

Line 2 abc orange abc

Line 3 abc banana abc

Line 4 abc pear abc

Line 5 abc apple abc
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
textarea.value = console.log(`${match}`);
```

Here is my regex:

```
const regex = /^(.*(apple|banana).*)$/gm;
const str = result;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }

    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
      if(match !== 'undefined' && groupIndex > 0)
        console.log(`${match}`);
    });
}
```

This is the result I want in my textbox (which is now displayed in my console):

```
Line 1 abc apple abc

Line 3 abc banana abc

Line 5 abc apple abc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```js
var l = "Line 1 abc apple abc\nLine 2 abc orange abc\nLine 3 abc banana abc\nLine 4 abc pear abc\nLine 5 abc apple abc";
var res = l.split("\n").filter(x => /apple|banana/.test(x)).join("\n");
console.log(res);
```

That is:

- Split the text into lines
- Filter all lines containing either `banana` or `apple`
- Join the matched lines (with `\n` or `<br>`, whatever works for you).

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, that worked like a charm!

I was then able to pass it like this

    textarea.value = res;